# Can this long matrix be split into multiple lines in the code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, matrix

I know strings in JS can be split into multiple lines, but what about a matrix?

```
$('#map').gameMap({map:[[{"tile":"grass_0","object":""},{"tile":"grass_0","object":""},{"tile":"grass_3","object":""}],[{"tile":"grass_0","object":""},{"tile":"grass_3","object":""},{"tile":"grass_0","object":""}],[{"tile":"grass_1","object":""},{"tile":"grass_0","object":""},{"tile":"grass_2","object":""}]],xpos:-1,ypos:-1,mapsize:3});
```

My supervisors like to see code contained on a single page, without having to scroll to view lengthy lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course it can...   You can break it up however you like, too, as long as you don't break in the middle of a string.

```
$('#map').gameMap(
      {map:[
         [
           {"tile":"grass_0","object":""},
           {"tile":"grass_0","object":""},
           {"tile":"grass_3","object":""}
         ],
         [
           {"tile":"grass_0","object":""},
           {"tile":"grass_3","object":""},
           {"tile":"grass_0","object":""}
         ],
         [
           {"tile":"grass_1","object":""},
           {"tile":"grass_0","object":""},
           {"tile":"grass_2","object":""}
         ]
     ],
     xpos:-1,
     ypos:-1,
     mapsize:3
     }
);
```

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript does not have a matrix data structure. What you have here is an object literal (`{ map : ... }`) which contains an array of arrays of object literals.

That aside, as others have pointed out, you certainly can break it up onto multiple lines, which also gives you an opportunity to add some sensible indentation, which will make it much, much easier to read and modify in the future. Personally I'm a fan of [comma-first style](https://gist.github.com/357981), which I think has both the most readability and the least potential for (programmer) error (i.e. missing commas) along with aligned colons (`:`) and a healthy dose of whitespace:

```
$('#map').gameMap(
  { map     : [ [ { "tile" : "grass_0", "object" : "" }
                , { "tile" : "grass_0", "object" : "" }
                , { "tile" : "grass_3", "object" : "" }
                ]
              , [ { "tile" : "grass_0", "object" : "" }
                , { "tile" : "grass_3", "object" : "" }
                , { "tile" : "grass_0", "object" : "" }
                ]
              , [ /* and so on... */
                ]
              ]
  , xpos    : -1
  , ypos    : -1
  , mapsize :  3
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this:

```
$('#map').gameMap({map:[[{"tile":"grass_0","object":""},
                         {"tile":"grass_0","object":""},
                         {"tile":"grass_3","object":""}],
                        [{"tile":"grass_0","object":""},
                         {"tile":"grass_3","object":""},
                         {"tile":"grass_0","object":""}],
                        [{"tile":"grass_1","object":""},
                         {"tile":"grass_0","object":""},
                         {"tile":"grass_2","object":""}]],
                   xpos:-1,
                   ypos:-1,
                   mapsize:3});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to tidy JavaScript code. Here is it's output:

```
$('#map').gameMap({
    map: [[{
        "tile": "grass_0",
        "object": ""},
    {
        "tile": "grass_0",
        "object": ""},
    {
        "tile": "grass_3",
        "object": ""}], [{
        "tile": "grass_0",
        "object": ""},
    {
        "tile": "grass_3",
        "object": ""},
    {
        "tile": "grass_0",
        "object": ""}], [{
        "tile": "grass_1",
        "object": ""},
    {
        "tile": "grass_0",
        "object": ""},
    {
        "tile": "grass_2",
        "object": ""}]],
    xpos: -1,
    ypos: -1,
    mapsize: 3
});
```